# UIView Touch event at the bottom of the screen not fired

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch, statusbar

I am encountering a strange problem. I created a UIView that takes place at the bottom of the screen
(0,431,320,49) and then I want to deal with touch events.

When I touch the upper side of the UIView, it works. But when I touch the bottom side (I mean, more than 20px in relative position), the touchBegan event is not fired.

It sounds like I have a problem with the network status bar that would change in some way the behavior of my code.

Does someone have any idea?

Regards,

Mathieu

Comment: Does this happen in the simulator too?

Comment: Please provided some code or more information..., difficult to figure out with the provided information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a transparent view above your UIView, it receives the touch event, and it does not pass those events to the view below it.
Or, another case I encountered, I assign the wrong frame to my view. The above views have a good looking, and touch event cannot be received at some point that is not contained in the wrong frame.

For example, I assigned frame (10,10,300,280) to my viewController's view, and add a subview with frame (0, 0, 320, 480) to the view. So the subview looks well, but touch event at point (0, 0) cannot be received.

Comment: OK I found the solution! I loaded my first view using a NIB with a frame (0,0,320,460) whereas the appearance was good. I changed to (0,0,320,480) and it worked perfectly ! Thank you so much !